# Detect Change in UISegmentedControl inside UITableView HeaderView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol, uitableviewsectionheader

I am trying to control my `UITableView` based on the `selectedSegmentIndex` of a `UISegmentedControl` inside my UITableView header. Essentially, I want this `UISegmentedControl` to work like Twitter's 'Me' tab. I have the `UISegmentedControl` inside a `UITableView` header and it is dequeued using this method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sectionDetailsHeaderView") as! SectionDetailsHeaderTableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

I have an outlet for the UISegmentedControl hooked up to `SectionDetailsHeaderTableViewCell`, but I can't figure out how to detect a change in the UISegmentedControl. I want to set a variable, `var segmentedControlValue = Int()` to the `selectedSegmentIndex` every time the value changes and call a function, `func chooseDataToDisplay() {}` when the value changes. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: without seeing more of your code, maybe your model has already detected the segment selected, but the view end of MVC needs updating accordingly. I'm wrestling with this very thing now.

Comment: Check out my answer below!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of @Schomes answer and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588941/uisegmentedcontrol-not-updating-view), I was able to figure it out!

1) Add the `UISegmentedControl` into its own `UITableViewCell`. I would recommend adding a `UIView` with a white background behind the `UISegmentedControl` that covers the entire `UITableViewCell` so the TableView cells flow behind the `UISegmentedControl`.

2) Add your custom cell class and hook it up to the `UITableViewCell`

3) Add an outlet, such as `yourSegmentedControl` to your custom `UITableViewCell` class. DO NOT add an action into the custom `UITableViewCell` class. This is done programmatically in step 4.

4) In the `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController` class, add the code below.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "yourCellIdentifier") as! yourCustomCellClass
    header.yourSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = self.segmentedControlValue
    header.yourSegmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.getSegmentValue(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    return header
}
```

`self.segmentedControlValue` should be declared as `var segmentedControlValue = Int()` at the top of your `ViewController` class. `self.getSegmentValue(sender:)` should be declared as:

```
func getSegmentValue(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    self.segmentedControlValue = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
}
```

5) You also need to add:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 45
}
```

This is the height of the header. In my case, the size is 45

6) You can now access `self.segmentedControlValue` anywhere in your `ViewController`. It will update when the user taps on a different segment.

Comment: Finally .. I had declared action in cell class and were using delegate to achieve the result, it was working but it has a flaws, then your answer made my night.. Thanks..

Comment: @AbhishekMitra Glad this helped! I just updated my answer to use dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView instead of dequeueReusableCell. Calling dequeueReusableCell can cause problems when reloading the UITableView

Comment: Yes, everything I used before seen your answer, only i had missed this line `header.yourSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = self.segmentedControlValue` in my code, and finally your answer helped to get over it. Thanks once again. I up voted your question and answers.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: "chooseDataToDisplay:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
```

Where `segmentedControl` is your UISegmentedControl. This will call `func chooseDataToDisplay(segment: UISegmentedControl) {}` every time the value changes.

References:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol

The section **Behavior of Segmented Controls**
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UISegmentedControl

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The selected segment never gets highlighted and the value never changes. I looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545198/swift-handle-action-on-segmented-control but it didn't help either.

Comment: Maybe look at these answers 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588941/uisegmentedcontrol-not-updating-view 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718956/problem-in-inserting-segmented-control-to-header-view

Comment: Awesome! This answer and one of the answers in your comment helped! I will post the answer that worked for me.